# Intel Thread Building Blocks Support for Windows Embedded Server 2012?

Tags: tbb, windows-server-2012

I want to know whether Intel Thread Building Blocks Support Windows Embedded Server 2012? In Release notes i have checked its written it supports **Microsoft* Windows* Server 2012** .But when i am checking difference between Microsoft Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 for Embedded Systems it is that Server for Embedded is designed for more specific scenarios, specific hardware (appliances), and purchase relationships (OEM channel).I want to know if Intel Thread Building Blocks (TBB) supports Windows server 2012 , is it likely that it will support windows server 2012 for embedded systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how Windows Server 2012 for Embedded is customized but there is high probability  that Intel TBB works there.

--Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

No it is not supported as the standard Intel Composer 2011 does not supports it.

Comment: TBB can be obtained as source and compiled by many compilers. Therefore the fact that Intel Composer 2011 does not support the target does not prevent TBB from being usable there. (TBB is used on SPARC, Power, ARM, ... for which there are no Intel compilers!)